# custom Log4j2 wrapper and output

Tags: java, logging, log4j, output, log4j2

I have an Custom Wrapper around Log4j2. and I have some problems on output, under the XXX line is what i want. but when I use "Log.info()"  I cant get the same result. any workaround except "Log .getLog().info()"

[image: output result]

here is code

```
public class TestMyLog {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Log.info("asdasggg");
    Log.debug("asdasda");
    Log.fatal("asdwefe");
    Log.error("fgggg");
    Log.warn("sdsdee");
    Log.trace("ioimom");
    System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    Log.getLog().info("sdss");
    Log.getLog().debug("dddddd");
    Log.getLog().error("erffs");

}
```

}

```
public class Log{
public static Log4j getLog(){
    return new Log4j2Wrapper();
}
public static void info(String str){
    new  Log4j2Wrapper().info(str);
}
public static void debug(String str){
    new  Log4j2Wrapper().debug(str);
}
public static void error(String str){
    new  Log4j2Wrapper().error(str);
}
public static void fatal(String str){
    new  Log4j2Wrapper().fatal(str);
}
public static void trace(String str){
    new  Log4j2Wrapper().trace(str);
}
public static void warn(String str){
    new  Log4j2Wrapper().warn(str);
}
public static boolean isInfoEnabled(){
    return new Log4j2Wrapper().isInfoEnabled();
}
public static boolean isDebugEnabled(){
    return new Log4j2Wrapper().isDebugEnabled();
}
public static boolean isErrorEnabled(){
    return new Log4j2Wrapper().isErrorEnabled();
}
public static boolean isFatalEnabled(){
    return new Log4j2Wrapper().isFatalEnabled();
}
public static boolean isWarnEnabled(){
    return new Log4j2Wrapper().isWarnEnabled();
}
public static boolean isTraceEnabled(){
    return new Log4j2Wrapper().isTraceEnabled();
}
```

}

```
public class Log4j2Wrapper implements Log4j{
private static final String FQCN = Log4j2Wrapper.class.getName();
private ExtendedLoggerWrapper log;

public Log4j2Wrapper() {
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    log = new ExtendedLoggerWrapper((ExtendedLogger) logger,
            logger.getName(), logger.getMessageFactory());
}

public boolean isInfoEnabled() {
    return log.isInfoEnabled();
}
public boolean isDebugEnabled() {
    return log.isDebugEnabled();
}
public boolean isErrorEnabled() {
    return log.isErrorEnabled();
}
public boolean isFatalEnabled() {
    return log.isFatalEnabled();
}
public boolean isWarnEnabled() {
    return log.isWarnEnabled();
}
public boolean isTraceEnabled() {
    return log.isTraceEnabled();
}
public void info(String str) {
    log.logIfEnabled(FQCN, Level.INFO, null, new SimpleMessage(str), null);
}
public void info(String str, Throwable t) {
    log.logIfEnabled(FQCN, Level.INFO, null, new SimpleMessage(str), t);
}
public void debug(String str){
    log.logIfEnabled(FQCN, Level.DEBUG,null,new SimpleMessage(str),null);
}
public void error(String str){
    log.logIfEnabled(FQCN, Level.ERROR,null,new SimpleMessage(str),null);
}
public void fatal(String str){
    log.logIfEnabled(FQCN, Level.FATAL,null,new SimpleMessage(str),null);
}
public void trace(String str){
    log.logIfEnabled(FQCN, Level.TRACE,null,new SimpleMessage(str),null);
}
public void warn(String str){
    log.logIfEnabled(FQCN, Level.WARN,null,new SimpleMessage(str),null);
}
```

}

```
public interface Log4j {
boolean isInfoEnabled();
boolean isDebugEnabled();
boolean isErrorEnabled();
boolean isFatalEnabled();
boolean isWarnEnabled();
boolean isTraceEnabled();
void info(String str);
void info(String str, Throwable t);
void debug(String str);
void error(String str);
void fatal(String str);
void warn(String str);
void trace(String str);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a custom Logger wrapper it becomes tricky to get location info right because Log4j2 walks the stacktrace for a number of steps to find that location, and your wrapper adds an extra StacktraceElement.

I recommend you create your custom wrapper using a Log4j2 tool: take a look at the [manual page for custom log levels](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html#CustomLoggers). This tool can generate code for a custom logger that correctly handles location information.

P.S.
Be aware that walking the stacktrace to find the logging location is very expensive in terms of performance. The [async logging page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#Location) has some concrete numbers. It's like throwing an exception with every log message.

Comment: thanks, but my purpose is to use Log.xxx directly without declare a logger object.

Comment: I suggest you use the tool to generate the wrapper, look at how it solves the location problem (fgcn) and use that in your Log class.

Comment: I'm using those commands in the manual to generate Extended logger and custom logger, but those throwing error

Answer (score 0):

If you use a PatternLayout in your log4j2.xml-file, i believe this pattern will give you the output you want.

```
pattern="%d{dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %-10logger{2} %-10M() ] %msg%n" />
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Loggers